# substitute for however

Tags: blog

I find myself using however much too often.  What's the best way around this?  Should I find a list of substitutes?  I'm thinking a better approach would be to fix my overall sentence structure and flow.  I don't have much in terms of official writing training.  I've been blogging a good bit and I feel I have good points to make, but I think my style and flow is just horrendous (as witnessed by this rambling question).  Any tips for a blogger to improve their writing ability?

Comment: Could you give an example? Sometimes writers think they have a problem, but the readers don't notice or care.

Comment: andersonbd1, your question is much too vague to answer. This is not a discussion forum as you probably know. A specific example would be helpful, then it would be a critique question (follow these guidelines: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). Otherwise your question will be closed, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your question, "Any tips for a blogger to improve their writing ability?" will have to remain unanswered, because it is too vague. However, I can address some of your other concerns, or at least point you in the right direction.

> Should I find a list of substitutes [for however]?

Similar questions to this have been asked and answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/alternatives-to-leading-a-sentence-with-the-conjunctive-adverb-however) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48862/difference-between-however-and-although) on our sister site [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), which is probably the best forum for individual word choices. There is also a discussion, of sorts, of the proper usage of *however* [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79/is-it-acceptable-to-start-a-sentence-with-however). Nevertheless, you should continue to ask Writers any writer-ly sort of questions you have, per the [FAQ](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq).

> What's the best way around [using however]?

This is a question we might be able to help with. But the answer will most likely be a variant of "use *however* sparingly" without any real sense of what that means. Just keep in mind that when you are using *however* you're making a statement that runs counter to the previous thought. Asking that question, "How do I best join two disparate thoughts?" could be a constructive style question to ask here.

> I don't have much in terms of official writing training.

Hey, I don't either. Formal training (i.e. college) helps. But as I'm sure you know, practice makes perfect. Having said that, feel free to ask for a critique by asking *specific question* about a *specific excerpt* as per [this discussion](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/clarification-of-critique-guidelines) on our meta side.

In any case, welcome to Writers. But for your next question, you might want to consider asking *one* question about a specific topic.